# tap search button trigger what event?

Tags: iphone

When I tap the search button on keyboard  display UISearchDisplayController what event it will trigger?

none of the event was triggered

```
- (void) searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller;
{

}
- (void) searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller;
{

}
- (void) searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller;
{

}
- (void) searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller;
{

}
// called when the table is created destroyed, shown or hidden. configure as necessary.
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{

}
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willUnloadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{

}

// called when table is shown/hidden
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{

}
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{

}
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willHideSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{

}
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didHideSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{

}
```

Welcome any comment

Comment: Can't you just slip in a NSLog in each method and see the sequence of the triggered calls?

Comment: u can check by own by setting break point in each method..

Comment: have you assigned the DELEGATE ?

Comment: I have set the breakpoint none above was triggered

Comment: I have set the delegate to the view controller that includes uiserachdisplaycontroller

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;                     // called when keyboard search button pressed
{


}
```

It need to use the function of UISearchbar rather than UISearchDisplayController